# Small caps table and section numbering

Tags: hyperref, numbering, captions, small-caps

I've formatted the table labels and section numbers to be in small caps. However, both when using `\autoref` and in the LOT, the table number is in lowercase letters. I'm not sure what I need to change.

**Note:** This is not about the label *Table* itself, but about the numbering *A.1*.

LOT and `\autoref`:

[image]

table caption label:

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}

\makeatletter
    \patchcmd\appendix{\@Alph\c@chapter}{\@alph\c@chapter}{}{}
    \renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
        \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
        {\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
            \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\linespread{0.7}\selectfont\raggedchapter#3}\hspace{\marginparsep}\formatchapternumber{#2}}\\*[-.5\baselineskip]
        \rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\par}
        {\@hangfrom\formatchapternumber{{#2}}{#3}}}
    \newcommand*{\formatchapternumber}[1]{\fontsize{40pt}{40pt}\usefont{U}{eur}{m}{n}\MakeUppercase{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{\MakeLowercase{#4}\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\marginparsep}\formatsectionnumber{#3}}}
    \newcommand*{\formatsectionnumber}[1]{\scshape#1}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}
\setkomafont{section}{\large\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat={\textsc{tab.~}}, numwidth=5em]{tocline}{table}

\usepackage[labelfont={sc}]{caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

    \listoftables

    \autoref{tab:test}

    \appendix
    \chapter{test}
    \section{test}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Test}\label{tab:test}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\alph{chapter}}` after `\appendix` solved the issue.